# Amplify mic even more

Tags: microphone

Is there a way to amplify the input audio even more then how far the slider goes on system preferences?

Maybe an application or something?

I am using line-in to pass a small signal through from the mic input, and I can hear it ok when it is quiet, just it needs a bit more volume.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of Microphone? Any pre-amplified microphone should be plenty loud (even too loud) when maxed. You may have to use a pre-amp of some sort, something like the [ART PowerMIX III](http://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/PowerMix3/) before plugging it into your computer.

Comment: This answer may change depending on your answer to what type of microphone it is.

Comment: I am actually using an audio induction pickup loop so I can "hear" what the hard drive etc sounds like magnetic wise. I can hear it fine, it just is not quite loud enough when I use linein, the input maxed, and the output maxed

Comment: Haha, wow. I do know what you're talking about, but I don't have any clue about what goes on to actually send the audio signal to have any sort of suggestion for this. Amplification in general stands as my answer, but it's hard to make a more specific recommendation.

Comment: I just want to do something similar to what VLC media player does where you can turn the volume up to 200% if it is a quiet movie

Comment: Wanting to intentionally overdrive your signal is not a standard feature of media players, so few have implemented is. My original answer still stands.

Comment: I Found a program named audio hijack pro and it allows the gain to go to 200%